# App lock gives error SD card full, Unable to move video to app lock

Tags: internal-storage, sd-card, micromax-yu-yureka, application-manager

The "App lock" app is giving an error saying my SD card is full and it is unable to move videos to App Lock. I am using a YU Yunicorn device, which has internal memory only, no Micro SD card.

Is there a reason I cannot add these files to the app?